# Unable to verify azure oauth2 jwt when graph.microsoft.net is the resource

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, jwt

We have a java application that needs to verify jwt tokens client side (access_token) coming from azure ad to get user information etc.

I have ran into an issue verifying the token when the resource is specified as graph.microsoft.com.

I have followed this example to verify the tokens
https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2017/01/24/Verifying-Azure-Active-Directory-JWT-Tokens.aspx

The tokens are being generated from 
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token

When the resource is set to graph.windows.net the token is valid and not valid for graph.microsoft.com.

When generating a token via client credentials flow in postman, the token is valid.  I am assuming this is because there is no resource specified.

Tokens generated with interactive login are invalid as they look up information in the graph and again valid for windows and not graph.

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong ?

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes , It won't verify a token that wasn't generated on the same domain as the Azure tenant.  So you can only validate graph.windows.net, graph.microsoft.com won't work.

Comment: Just a reminder, after you login through Azure SSO, you will get multiple tokens, and the only token that you need to verify is idToken, because its intended for you, and do not verify accessToken, that is intended for Microsoft Graph.

I have been trying to validation accessToken for days, turns out it is not for us.